# Serialisation of an Object Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, java-io

I would like to serialise/deserialise an object. Code runs but the result in the txt is crap.

Here is the code :

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
    public String[] nom;


    public Test() {

        nom = new String[5];
        nom[0] = "Coucou";
        nom[1] = "Je suis un tab de String";
        nom[2] = "Je vais me faire serialiser";
        nom[3] = "Et deserialiser aussi !";
        nom[4] = "Je suis le roi du monde !";
    }

}
```

In the main :

```
    Test test = new Test();
    File f = new File ("nom.txt");


  try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (f))) {
            oos.writeObject (test);
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
        System.out.println ("Erreur lors de l'écriture : " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    ObjectInputStream ois =  new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)) ;

    Test test2 = (Test)ois.readObject();

    System.out.println(test2.nom[0]);
    System.out.println(test2.nom[1]);
    System.out.println(test2.nom[2]);
    System.out.println(test2.nom[3]);
    System.out.println(test2.nom[4]);
```

The result in the txt file is :

> ¬í sr tp.java.Testp32< [ nomt [Ljava/lang/String;xpur
>   [Ljava.lang.String;­ÒVçé{G  xp   t Coucout Je suis un tab de
>   Stringt Je vais me faire serialisert Et deserialiser aussi !t Je
>   suis le roi du monde !

The console show the result of the deserialization, which is perfect :

```
Coucou 
Je suis un tab de String 
Je vais me faire serialiser 
Et deserialiser aussi ! 
Je suis le roi du monde !
```

Any idea ? Is it a UTF-8 problem ?

Comment: Looks perfect to me. Serialisation is not human readable. What's your issue exactly??

Comment: If you want to serialize in some text/human readable format, serialize to JSON or XML

Comment: I didn't know that serialisation is not human readable... ._.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it was? Or were you just guessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how actually serialization works, it doesn't write a readable text file but shorted version of object fields.